# How to keep a sorted data structure according to a custom criteria

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have defined an ordering array as:

```
String[] orderingArray = {"tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"};
```

This array would be used to define ordering for my upcoming list.

Now, three different threads are posting their respective lists (from network) asynchronously and at arbitrary time, on the main UI thread. All the objects returned in the respective lists have a tag value, which can be either of "tag1", "tag2"...

I need to maintain a single list on the main thread which should be ordered according to the values defined in the orderingArray i.e all "tag1" objects should be first, and so on.

The threads can post anytime and in any order from the Pool they are executing in, and at all times the main list should remain ordered according to the array. Brute-force way would be to comparator sort the list everytime any thread posts its individual list.

Any ideas, suggestions, on how to achieve this efficiently ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried executing all the 3 threads using a synchronizer, so that all tagged objects come in serial order, and thus prevent this problem altogether. But now, I need to execute them in parallel, so that end user does not wait much. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) for this task, the `Set` will be based on a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that first checks the tags and then defines which is bigger. You most likely are going to need some tie breaker as well in case of many elements with the same tag.

The sorted by nature data structures ensures each element is inserted into its correct position relatively efficiently, and this implementation allows concurrent modifications.